# GIT Versioning strategy for a monorepo that has different set of framework libraries

Tags: node.js, git, continuous-integration, git-branch, monorepo

I am analyzing the monorepo strategy for some of my framework node modules / libraries that are currently part of different repos. I have around two dozen node modules / libraries and not all of them are used by a single application. Few applications just use a single node module / library whereas others use 5+ of them. I am using a semver for these modules.

If i move to monorepo, what would be the best GIT branching strategy in the following scenario

- I planned to support only the two major versions of a module at any time. (latest & latest -1). Latest should have all enhancements & breaking changes. latest - 1  is to support bug fixes of previous release. What would be the best branching model for this scenario ? Note, another developer in my team may modify a different module for bug fixing or he / she may add new enhancements to a module. How do we separate our changes inside a single repo ? what is a proven branching model in this scenario